# Datatable on dynamic generated table with json data

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
$.ajax({
        url:'http://localhost/PopUp/data.json',
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(res){
            console.log(res)
            var data='';
            data+=' <table class="display" style="width:100%">\
            <thead>\
            <tr>\
            <th>Name</th>\
            <th>Mobile</th>\
            <th>Stage</th>\
            </tr>\
            </thead>';
            $.each(res,function(k,v){
                data+='<tbody>\
                <tr>\
                <td>'+v.name+'</td>\
                <td>'+v.Mobile+'</td>\
                <td>'+v.stage+'</td>\
                </tr>\
                </tbody>';
            })
            data+='</table>';

            $("#display").append(data);
            $('.display').dataTable({
                columns: [
                {'data': 'name' },
                {'data': 'Mobile' },
                {'data': 'stage' }
                ],
            });

        }

    })
```

My table is generated dynamically according to my requirement . I am trying to apply datatable on it . Datatable is applied but datatable features are not working.
Thank you..

Comment: Try changing `$('.display')` to `$(document).find('.display')`, that might solve the problem.

Comment: No this didn't work for me